# Google Drive API Historical quota data

Tags: google-drive-api

I had an interesting experience with my Google account quota, which could be solved with access to the following information (if it exists!).  Basically, can I get my Google account quota data WITH a time stamp?  In other words, can I determine how much memory my account was allocated on a certain date?

Context: I had 122 GB allocated because I was paying for 100GB extra memory.  At some point I cleared the memory to get back down to under 22GB used, so I cancelled the 100GB extra memory subscription.  Upon doing so, my total allocated storage dropped to 17GB.  When I asked why the support simply said 15GB+2GB for the security update (from 2016).  And they said there is no historical record so they couldn't verify the 122GB number, and I do not know how I ended up with 20GB of memory +2 for the security update.  I also didn't think about taking screenshots with these numbers before cancelling the subscription because this is Google we're talking about and I figured they had all this kind of data in case something went wrong.  I've had a Google account since 2005 so I'm thinking maybe at some point I picked up a 5GB bonus somehow.

Anyway, I'm a data scientist so even if there's a complicated way to get this kind of info I'd be interested in hearing what kind of data is available that might verify my account of the memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post from [Google Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/5MRWDUzt93g) may help you.

> The first thing to note is that when you delete or remove files from
>   your google drive storage quota, you will want to empty your trash in
>   order to free up that space.  If you have orphaned files, you can find
>   them In the Drive search field, type: is:unorganized owner:me
>
> Your Google Drive Storage Quota consist of Google Drive, Google
>   Photos, and Gmail files.  Sometimes changes made to your google drive
>   account will take the google servers 24-48 hours to properly sync and
>   reflect back to your drive.  Usually this takes far less time but it
>   can happen.  Here are some helpful links I use when managing my google
>   drive storage quota:

There is no 'history' option but if you want to to check your storage, here is the [path](https://www.google.com/settings/storage) that will lead you. From there you will see how much is the capacity of your account can use.

To see how much each of your files is taking up the quota, you may visit [this link](https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/quota).

If you want to manage your quota, you may check [this link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409676?hl=en) for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, after exhausting the externally facing Google Drive support services (along with equally unhelpful emails back and forth) I doubt my answer lies at the end of a link, unless there is one which summarizes all the possible ways in which bonus memory was given out over the years, which I haven't been able to find.